# How to create Custom Action In FileProviderUI

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios11

According to [WWDC Session 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/243/) In last 10 minutes of video the presenters have mentioned about custom actions.
In this case Operations are scoped to files from your extension and Interface is provided by a UI extension.

I tried implementing the same but was unsussessfull, This is a new feature and could't find any data related to this feature.

Anyone tried this feature? Is there any sample code/ app for the same?

Comment: Hi, I'm also interested in this feature and building sample project for it. But I haven't encountered any difficulties, seems that documentation of NSFileProviderEnumerator, NSFileProviderExtension, FileProviderItem is pretty nice. Also 'File Provider Extension' and 'File Provider UI Extension' XCode templates have nice comments in functions, that needs to be implemented. Maybe you have more specific questions, what do you need to implement or what kind of issues trying to solve? Or you need just working sample project with custom action defined in the files' context menu?

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko  it would be great if you could share sample project with custom action.

Comment: Please check my sample project, I will add more explanation in the answer if it will work for you https://github.com/tkach/FileProviderSample

Comment: @Jaiswal checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple doc

> Define custom actions in your File Provider UI extension's Info.plist
>   file. These actions appear in the context menu when the user long
>   presses an item while browsing your file provider's content.

You need to add this value in File Provider UI extension's Info.plist file

```
<key>NSExtensionFileProviderActions</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionFileProviderActionIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.example.MyFileProvider.setRating</string>
        <key>NSExtensionFileProviderActionName</key>
        <string>Rate</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

for more details checkout this link 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileproviderui/adding_actions

Comment: Hey, do you know a way to present an FPUIActionExtensionViewController other than throwing an error in the enumerator? I have a use-case where the filetype maybe unsupported and I'm trying to return an error when the user taps such file. Returning an error anywhere other than the enumerate block doesn't trigger the UI :(

Comment: Can we dynamically change name of action ?